# Select Like and if found, add a column showing the results

Tags: sql-server, select, text, sql-like

I apologize for the lack of information in my question. I am using MS SQL. I am looking for 3 specific items in a text field; IH-, MPC, or ICC. If any of these items are found in the text field, I would like to show that they have been found. If all three have been found in the first row, there would be a field that included IH-, MPC, ICC
Here is my query;

```
SELECT     tt.TITLE, tt.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID, tt.VERSION, PATH_MAPPINGS.PATH, tt.CONTENT
FROM         ITEM_REFERENCES INNER JOIN
PATH_MAPPINGS ON ITEM_REFERENCES.ORGANIZATIONAL_ITEM_ID = PATH_MAPPINGS.ORGANIZATIONAL_ITEM_ID INNER 
JOIN
ITEMS AS tt INNER JOIN

                      (SELECT     ITEM_REFERENCE_ID, MAX(VERSION) AS MaxVersion
FROM          ITEMS
                        GROUP BY ITEM_REFERENCE_ID) AS groupedtt ON tt.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID = groupedtt.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID AND tt.VERSION = groupedtt.MaxVersion ON
ITEM_REFERENCES.ID = tt.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID

WHERE    (tt.CONTENT LIKE  '%<text>AP[0-2]%'  )
or

(tt.CONTENT LIKE  '%<text>IH-[0-2]%'  )
or

(tt.CONTENT LIKE  '%<text>MPC[0-2]%'  )
or
(tt.CONTENT LIKE  '%<text>ICC[0-2]%'  )
```

Comment: In my opinion, this should be scripted. MySQL simply cannot add columns dynamically by itself.
You can loop through all the columns `IF(title LIKE ..., 1, 0) AS matched_on_title, etc..`

Comment: Why do you need this, is it not an option to add all the options, and then in your script do a boolean comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simplified data table with only the content one idea is to create a temporary table holding the search criteria to check them against the original data.

The temporary table can be a `CTE` like in the following query

```
WITH ContentPattern AS (
  SELECT '%blue%' c
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '%red%'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '%at%'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '%green%'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '%orange%'
)
SELECT a.[field], f.Found
FROM   Table1 a
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cp.c
                                  FROM   ContentPattern cp 
                                  WHERE  PATINDEX(cp.c, a.[field]) > 0
                                  GROUP BY cp.c
                                  HAVING COUNT(cp.c) > 0
                                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                                 , 1, 1, '') Found) f
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6fc4be/5)</kbd>

In the question the patterns have a variable part, changing the values of the `CTE` will suffice, but it's possible to do a little more: get the real value instead of the search criteria. To do this we need the length of the pattern, and the easiest way to get it is... to pre-calculate it, in some way, and add it to the temp table/`CTE`

```
WITH ContentPattern AS (
  SELECT '%blue[0-2]%' c, 5 l
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '%red[0-2]%', 4 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '%at[0-2]%', 3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '%green%', 5
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '%orange%', 6
)
SELECT a.[field], f.Found
FROM   Table1 a
       CROSS APPLY (
             SELECT STUFF((
                    SELECT ', ' 
                         + SUBSTRING(a.[field], PATINDEX(cp.c, a.[field]), cp.l)
                    FROM   ContentPattern cp 
                    WHERE  PATINDEX(cp.c, a.[field]) > 0
                    GROUP BY cp.c, cp.l
                    HAVING COUNT(cp.c) > 0
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                  ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                  , 1, 1, '') Found) f
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7a60/7)</kbd>

As the field is in the query it'll stand in the result even if none of the content has the searched pattern, with a `NULL` value, a `WHERE` condition on the `LEN` of the `Found` field can remove all the row that doesn't match.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information. I am using MS SQL and I am actually trying to search a field of text which could contain any of three choices; IH-, MPC, or ICC. Here is the code I have so far;

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to make this work with my query I recently added in my question. This is what I am looking for though. Have you looked at my existing code yet?

Comment: Yep, this is what I would want. Also, I provided my sample query with desired search criteria in my original question. Are you able to see that? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, I saw your query, but I preferred to work with a simplified example to point out the method, I'll update the answer

Comment: Look like it will work. The only problem is I have no idea right now how to make this work with my query. I will have to work with it. It will take a while. THanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Case When FIELD Like '%BLUE%' Then 'BLUE'
       Else When FIELD Like '%RED%' Then 'RED'
       Else When FIELD Like '%AT%' Then 'AT' End
From Table
Where (FIELD Like '%BLUE%'
      Or FIELD Like '%RED%'
      Or FIELD Like '%AT%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres:

```
select 
  (blue like '%blue%') as found_blue,
  (blue like '%red%') as found_red 
from (select '***blue***'::text as blue) t;

 found_blue │ found_red 
────────────┼───────────
 t          │ f
(1 row)
```

MySql:

```
select    
 (blue like '%blue%') as found_blue,   
 (blue like '%red%') as found_red  
 from (select '***blue***' as blue) t;
+------------+-----------+
| found_blue | found_red |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 |         0 |
+------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```